# Why does strcpy fail with char *s but not with char s[1024]?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why does the following happen:

```
char s[2] = "a";
strcpy(s,"b");
printf("%s",s);
```

--> executed without problem

```
char *s = "a";
strcpy(s,"b");
printf("%s",s);
```

--> segfault

Shouldn't the second variation also allocate 2 bytes of memory for `s` and thus have enough memory to copy `"b"` there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't the second variation also allocate 2 bytes of memory for s and thus have enough memory to copy "b" there?

No, `char *s` is pointing to a static memory address containing the string `"a"` (writing to that location results in the segfault you are experiencing) whereas `char s[2];` itself provides the space required for the string.

If you want to manually allocate the space for your string you can use dynamic allocation:

```
char *s = strdup("a"); /* or malloc(sizeof(char)*2); */
strcpy(s,"b");
printf("%s",s); /* should work fine */
```

Don't forget to `free()` your string afterwards.

Comment: You mean, I should call free after I am finished with `s`, right?

Answer (score 12):

```
char *s = "a";
```

The pointer `s` is pointing to the string literal `"a"`. Trying to write to this has undefined behaviour, as on many systems string literals live in a read-only part of the program.

It is an accident of history that string literals are of type `char[N]` rather than `const char[N]` which would make it much clearer.

Comment: String literals are of type `char[N]`, where N is the length of the literal including nul terminator. But yes, it should be `const char[N]`, and indeed it is in C++, which is stricter than C about const-correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Altogather a different way/answer : I think the mistake is that you are not creating a variable the pointer has to point to and hence the seg fault.

**A rule which I follow** : Declaring a pointer variable will not create the type of variable, it points at. It creates a pointer variable. So in case you are pointing to a string buffer you need to specify the character array and a buffer pointer and point to the address of the character array.